# Robot drift while and after turns

Tags: webots

I am teleoperating a tricycle robot(froklift) in Webots. I am facing a problem while turning the robot. to and fro motion of the vehicle is OK. But after a small turn or a sharp one the robot skids in the normal direction of motion.

To me this can be because of kinematics constraints of the vehicles.

1. Rolling constraint: is OK as the robot works fine
2. Sliding constraint: this is violated while turning the robot

Kindly guide me if this is the problem than How can I solve it?

Or is there any other issue or a parameter needed to be tuned.

The robot have one active castor wheel for linear and angular motion. Apart from this all are passive wheels.

Edited:

- Just going through the code for controller I noticed that steer motor is being updated all the time which accumulates position updates over time and I think for skidding it is responsible
- Rotation motor is being used in velocity mode and steer motor is being used in position mode. However it has initial velocity of 10.0(Max velocity) I think it is making the drift

#### Code

```py
while fts.step(timestep) != -1:
    key = keys.getKey()
    if(key == keys.UP):
        state = MAX_SPEED
        wheel_main_steer_motor.setPosition(0.0)
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setVelocity(state)
        print("Main Motor position:", wheel_main_rotation_postion_sensor.getValue())
        print("Main Motor velocity",wheel_main_rotation_motor.getVelocity())
        print("Steer Motor position:", wheel_main_steer_position_sensor.getValue())        
        print("Steer Motor velocity",wheel_main_steer_motor.getVelocity())
    elif(key == keys.DOWN):
        state = -MAX_SPEED
        wheel_main_steer_motor.setPosition(0.0)
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setVelocity(state)
        print("Main Motor position:", wheel_main_rotation_postion_sensor.getValue())
        print("Main Motor velocity",wheel_main_rotation_motor.getVelocity())
        print("Steer Motor position:", wheel_main_steer_position_sensor.getValue())        
        print("Steer Motor velocity",wheel_main_steer_motor.getVelocity())
    elif(key == keys.RIGHT):
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setVelocity(state)
        wheel_main_steer_motor.setPosition(-0.5)
        print("Main Motor position:", wheel_main_rotation_postion_sensor.getValue())
        print("Main Motor velocity",wheel_main_rotation_motor.getVelocity())
        print("Steer Motor position:", wheel_main_steer_position_sensor.getValue())        
        print("Steer Motor velocity",wheel_main_steer_motor.getVelocity())
    elif(key == keys.LEFT):
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setVelocity(state)
        wheel_main_steer_motor.setPosition(0.5)
        print("Main Motor position:", wheel_main_rotation_postion_sensor.getValue())
        print("Main Motor velocity",wheel_main_rotation_motor.getVelocity())
        print("Steer Motor position:", wheel_main_steer_position_sensor.getValue())        
        print("Steer Motor velocity",wheel_main_steer_motor.getVelocity())
    else:
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
        wheel_main_rotation_motor.setVelocity(0.0)
        wheel_main_steer_motor.setPosition(0.0)
        print("Main Motor position:",     wheel_main_rotation_postion_sensor.getValue())
        print("Main Motor velocity",wheel_main_rotation_motor.getVelocity())
        print("Steer Motor position:", wheel_main_steer_position_sensor.getValue())        
        print("Steer Motor velocity",wheel_main_steer_motor.getVelocity())
```

Comment: Very difficult to answer without seeing the model. It can come from physics parameters, issues in hierarchy, issues in controller, etc.

Comment: @FabienRohrer edited the post.